# How can I find files added to the system within X minutes of a specific time?

Tags: macos, mac, time

I have done a fresh install of Mac OS X Mountain Lion today on a new MacBook.

Because this was a new install, when I finally got round to configuring some of my own developer things, I was surprised to find some app had installed a binary into `/usr/local/bin` - a single binary called `galileod`.

Interestingly, I can't find *anything* online about `galileod`. I had only installed the bare minimum of software at this point.

Looking in the file columns I can see Date Modified was 9th November 2012, but **Date Added to the system was today at 17:01**.

It's now 10:20PM and I can't remember which software I was installing at that point. So how do I find out which other files were installed to the system within, say, 5 minutes either side of 17:01?

**EDIT:** I found out what `galileod` was by running `galileod --help` - it is a binary used with Fitbit to communicate with the USB dongle. So that's the mystery solved - but it would still be interesting to know how to find files added within X minutes of a timeframe for future reference.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `find` to find files that were created in the last N minutes. From `man find`:

```
  -mmin n
          File's data was last modified n minutes ago.
```

So, for example, if it is now 18:30 and you want files created between 17:45 and 18:00, i.e. created more than 30 minutes ago but less than 45 minutes ago, you would do this:

```
sudo find / -mmin +30 -mmin -45
```

Answer (score 3):

The date added metadata has only been around [since 10.7](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40941/how-do-so-set-date-added-metadata-in-mac-os-x-10-7-lion). It might be stored only in the Spotlight indexes.

```
mdfind 'kMDItemDateAdded>=$time.now(-3600)'
```

Comment: This is the 'correct' way to do it in OS X.

Answer (score 1):

You can find modified files in the last n days:

```
sudo find / -mtime -1 -print
```

It's a start...

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-finding-files-by-date/